# Equivalent of Linux sync_file_range system call on windows?

Tags: winapi, filesystems, ntfs, kernel32, windows-kernel

I need to fsync a range of byte I appended to a file without forcing a flush on the metadata (filesize,...).

Comment: What language? In ring0 or ring3 ?

Comment: In ring3 with C or C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said it's ring3 and it's C++, here is the answer:

You need to call `FlushViewOfFile` after mapping the file. According to MSDN:

> The FlushViewOfFile function does not flush the file metadata, and it
>   does not wait to return until the changes are flushed from the
>   underlying hardware disk cache and physically written to disk.

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

An example code that writes data and uses FlushViewOfFile is here: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?367742-FlushViewOfFile-does-not-Flush